# R: connect points on a graph (ggplot2)

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, line, point

Suppose I have data in the following form:

```
library(ggplot2)

Data <- data.frame(
    
    "ID" = c("ABC111", "ABC111", "ABC111", "ABC111", "ABC112", "ABC112", "ABC112", "ABC113", "ABC113", "ABC114", "ABC115"),
"color" = c("red", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green", "black", "yellow"),
    "start_date" = c("2005/01/01", "2006/01/01", "2007/01/01", "2008/01/01", "2009/01/01", "2010/01/01", "2011/01/01", "2012/01/01", "2013/01/01", "2014/01/01", "2015/01/01"),
    "end_date" = c("2005/09/01", "2006/06/01", "2007/04/01", "2008/05/07", "2009/06/01", "2010/10/01", "2011/12/12", "2013/05/01", "2013/06/08", "2015/01/01", "2016/08/09")
)

Data$ID = as.factor(Data$ID)
Data$color = as.factor(Data$color)
```

Now what I want to do is for each row, plot the start_date and the end_date ... and then connect them with a straight line. I believe this can be done with geom_line() in ggplot2.

I want something that looks like this:[image]

I tried using the following code:

```
q <- qplot(start_date, end_date, data=Data)
q <- q + geom_line(aes(group = ID))
q
```

But the graph looks completely different than what I expected.

Can anyone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In the plot you show, what are the y-axis values?

Comment: hello! the y-axis in this plot is meaningless ... it would be nice if the lines could be "staked" in the order of they appear in. is this possible to do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` package. I used the number of each row in the original data as the y-axis values in the plot. As these values are meaningless, I removed the y-axis title, labels and ticks from the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

Data %>%
  # Number each row in its order of appearance, 
  # save this numbers in a new column named order
  rowid_to_column("order") %>%
  # Change data from wide to long format
  pivot_longer(cols = c(start_date, end_date),
               names_to = "date_type",
               values_to = "date") %>%
  # Ggplot, use date as x, order as y, ID as col and order as group
  ggplot(aes(x = date, 
             y = order,  
             col = ID, 
             group = order)) +
  # Draw points
  geom_point()+
  # Draw lines
  geom_line() +
  # Maybe you want to remove the y axis title, text and ticks
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        # I added a vertical format to the x axis labels 
        # it might easier to read this way
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: points-linesplot]

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work for you?

```
ggplot(data = Data, aes(start_date, end_date, color = ID))+
  geom_line(aes(group = ID))+
  geom_point()
```

or maybe `geom_segment` ?

```
# Adding x and y coordinates for geom_segment
Data$x <- as.character(as.Date(Data$start_date) + (as.Date(Data$end_date) - as.Date(Data$start_date)))
Data$y <- 1:nrow(Data)

ggplot(data = Data, aes(x, y, colour = ID))+
  geom_segment(aes(xend = start_date, yend = end_date))
```

Comment: hello! thank you for your reply. not exactly - I would like all the lines to be horizontal. and each line is just made of two points (from that row). is this possible to do?

Comment: Then, you may not have the right data. You are probably looking for something like `geom_segment`, in which case you need to provide further information about `x` and `y` axis.  check if my edits can help you.